# how could the const char * changed?

Tags: char, gdb, constants

I am writing a program which can print the directory recursively,
below is the gdb debug segment

note that the d_path (it is a const char * passed as a parameter to print_dir_tree)
is "/home/cifer/.gftp" before step to "if (dr == NULL) {"
however,  it is printed "/home/cifer/!\200" after this clause

who can tell me why?
thanks a lot!

```
Breakpoint 1, print_dir_tree (d_path=0x805b058 "/home/cifer/.gftp", depth=4)

    at dir_demo.c:15

15      DIR *dr = opendir(d_path);

(gdb) print d_path

$2 = 0x805b058 "/home/cifer/.gftp"

(gdb) print d_path

$3 = 0x805b058 "/home/cifer/.gftp"

(gdb) step

16      if (dr == NULL) {

(gdb) print d_path

$4 = 0x805b058 "/home/cifer/!\200"

(gdb) step

20      struct dirent *de = NULL;

(gdb) print d_path

$5 = 0x805b058 "/home/cifer/!\200"

(gdb) step

21      while((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL) {

(gdb) print d_path

$6 = 0x805b058 "/home/cifer/!\200"

(gdb)
```

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the code; could be reliance on undefined behvaiour, could be a buffer overflow somewhere.  You should create a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Are there other threads - are they disabled during debug? Is there a timeout while debugging the cleans up the memory of dr while you are busy debugging? Can you replicate with a very simple program?

Comment: now i paste the whole code ....

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see your code to tell for sure but if you are asking if a const can be changed the answer is yes. If you are asking how it can be changed, that is simple, it is treated just like a regular variable but it will give you a warning when it is changed. If you are trying to change it and avoid a warning you can copy the variable and then make changes to it.